# Tikz: Different fill-pattern in pdf-document than in preview

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, compiling

I've got a strange problem (at least for me it is strange). I've put a lot of work in a Tikz-picture and finally it was finished and I was happy with the result my TeXstudio showed me in the preview. But when I opened it in Acrobat Reader there was a little but annoying difference: The dash pattern I used for my \fill command was just ignored. Instead the PDF just showed me horizontal lines.

My first question is: Do you have any idea where this difference comes from?

But my real question is: What can I do to make the dashed pattern appear in the pdf?

I already tried changing my standard-compiler from PdfLaTeX to LaTeX, but that didn't change anything. Below is my picture in a standalone.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Update: I imported the PDF with Gimp and suddenly the picture appeared with dashed lines. Maybe that's only a problem with the Adobe Reader?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[pattern=horizontal lines, dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt on 3pt off 2pt on 1pt off 2pt] (0.8,0) arc (-75:210:3.18) arc (30:-30:3) arc (150:435:3.18) -- cycle;
\draw[] (0.8,0) arc (-75:210:3.18) arc (30:-30:3) arc (150:435:3.18) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (0,3.1) circle (3) node {+};
\draw[fill=white] (0,-3.1) circle (3) node {+};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture with a filling of definitely-not-dashed lines]

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with Adobe Reader, however it works fine with Evince, xpdf, Okular.

Comment: you haven't dashed the pattern you basically defined a dash pattern and then filled with horizontal solid lines. Whatever you are seeing as dashed is the wrong behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to percusse, who got me the right hint.

When I do something like:

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[4pt]{MyHorizLines}{\pgfqpoint{-4pt}{-4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{12pt}{12pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}%
{
\pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.3pt}
%\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
%\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\GridSize}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.1pt}{0pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
```

}

and use it as pattern:

```
\fill[pattern=MyHorizLines]
```

adobe shows me the dashed lines too.

Many thanks!